# Google Password I didn't create

Tags: password-management, account-security, google

I opened Google, and a popup occurred briefly before I reflexively closed it.  I then realized it had said something about a new password saved to the Google Password Manager, I think - which is weird, because I don't use Google's Password Manager.  So I went and checked, and yep, there was one password saved to the manager.  It says it's for Wish.  I then checked a few other things, but google says there've been no new sign ins, and I think all the active sign-ins are mine.  I exported the password list, and it's a little odd - here's a redacted version:

```
name,url,username,password
,android://[GIBBERISH THAT LOOKS LIKE BASE 64]@com.contextlogic.wish/,[MY EMAIL ADDRESS],
```

(The base-64 doesn't decode properly, and the parts of it that do are still gibberish.)

Note that the name and the password field are both apparently blank.  And that the url looks like some kind of custom android URI rather than a proper URL.

I've changed my Google password, just in case, but it's sortof baffling how this could have occurred.  If nobody else was signed in to my account, they shouldn't have been able to add a saved password, and I haven't gone to Wish or clicked any related links in months, AFAIK.  Anybody know what's up?

Comment: Google uses on oAuth based login system so changing the password will as far as I know not log your account out from persistent logged in devices. So you should also check the Manage devices section in the Google Account page.  https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3067630?hl=en

Comment: You should do something about that habit of yours of clicking away popups without reading them. There's worse that can happen than an unwanted entry in Google Password Manager.

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt If I didn't get dozens of unimportant (or spam) popups in a day, I'd consider it.  Unfortunately, due to overuse, popups do not carry the same UI significance they may once have.

Comment: There's probably something to check up on there.  I'm struggling to think of the last popup I got period, much less in the last week or certainly day.  Maybe I just have an abnormally short trigger for software which does things I didn't ask for.